# Multipart response handling in apigee

Tags: apigee

Has anyone tried parsing a multi-part response from backend in apigee layer?

Let's say we have a 2 part response one with a plain text part and other with xml part, what if i just want to take the xml part and convert it to json. Can i do that?

If anyone can provide a sample custom script to do that,it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

So one request responds with some XML as well as plain text in the same response?

I would think you need to look at using the javascript policy to write a custom parser